# What is the optimum list of previous Star Wars movies that I should watch before December 18

Tags: star-wars, sequels

I'm really fascinated about Star Wars movies.I'm passing the 3rd decade of my life time on Earth, however I've never actually see or had any chance to watch at least a single Star Wars movie. But my ambition is to rise up early at December 18th and walk straight to the theater to watch "Star Wars: The Force Awakens"

I assume the first movie is 
"Episode IV: A New Hope (1977)"

And the latest one will debut on December 18th
"Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015)"

So there's too much to catch up. But if any STAR WARS die hard fan could give me the optimum list of previous movies that I should watch before December 18, it would be really appreciated.